# Trying to Sort and Merge two vectors

Tags: sorting, vector, merge

1. Trying to Sort and Merge two Vectors
2. keep getting this error:
   c:\users\austin\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\hw 16\hw 16\h16.cpp(42): error C3861: 'lowestVal': identifier not found
3. How could i improve my code

   vector mergeSorted(const vector& a, const vector& b)
   {
       vector result;
       int m = 0;

   ```
   if (a.size() < b.size())
   {
       m = a.size();
   }
   else
   {
       m = b.size();
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
   {
       result.push_back(a[i]);
       result.push_back(b[i]);
   }

   if (m == a.size())
   {
       result.insert(result.end(), b.begin() + m, b.end());
   }
   if (m == b.size())
   {
       result.insert(result.end(), a.begin() + m, a.end());
   }

   for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
   {
       //function that checks for lowest val
       result.insert(result.begin() + lowestVal(result, a[i]), a[i]);
   }

   return result;
   ```

   }

   int lowestVal(const vector& v, int val)
   {

   ```
   for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
   {
       if (val < v[i])
       {
           return i;
       }
       else
       {
           return v.size();
       }

   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the declaration of lowestVal before it is called:

```
int lowestVal(const vector& v, int val);
vector mergeSorted(const vector& a, const vector& b) { // ...
```

This is called [forward declaration](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/17-forward-declarations/). Compiler must know the type of the identifier, so it must be declared before using.

Comment: thanks! but now i for some reason one of my loops are going out of bounds